# document.querySelector with from attributes returns null error

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all, I'm learning JS and jQuery. I'm trying to copy the content of a form field on the left/right to the same field on the right/left with a button.
The transfer function returns "null", so I guess it doesn't find the element in the DOM. I've tried different syntax, but I can't fix it.

Here's the snippet : https://jsfiddle.net/wc8mzz3p/149/

```
<div id='main'>
        <div id="rightSidePanel" class="ui form">
                <div id="compareForm" class="fields grid-no-margin">
                    <div id="prjFormLeft" class="seven wide field">
            <div class='ui stackable one column grid grid-no-margin tab active'>
            <div class='column field'><label for='Customer'>Customer</label><input type='text' field='Customer' name='Customer'></input><div class='ui item'>
            <button class='ui right floated icon button' for='Customer' side='Left' onclick='transfer(this)'>
            <i class='right chevron icon'></i></button>
             //--lots of other fields
        </div></div></div></div>
          <div id="prjFormRight" class="seven wide field">
            <div class='ui stackable one column grid grid-no-margin tab active'>
            <div class='column field'><label for='Customer'>Customer</label><input type='text' id='Customer' name='Customer'></input><div class='ui item'><button class='ui icon button' for='Customer' side='Right' onclick='transfer(this)'><i class='left chevron icon'></i></button></div></div>
             //--lots of other fields
         </div></div></div></div>
```

JS function:

```
function transfer(element) {
   var from = element.getAttribute('side');
   var field = element.getAttribute('for');
   if(from === 'Right') var dest = 'Left';
   else var dest = 'Right';
   var destElement = document.querySelector("#prjForm"+dest+" label[for='"+field+"']");
   console.log(destElement);
}
```

Comment: This seems a lot more complicated than it needs to be. There should be a way to genericise your JS code. Could you please post the output HTML instead of the PHP spaghetti.

Comment: What is the value of `from` and `side` ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan what do you mean by output HTML ?
the value of from/side is right or left

Comment: As in, the code that you see in your browser when you click 'View Source'

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it's edited, i hope it helps

Comment: Kudos for posting the code, but please take a moment to read the "*[mcve]*" guidelines; we don't need - or *want* - *all* the code, just the absolute minimum that allows us to reproduce the problem. So, with this question, we really need the 'left' and 'right' elements, and any other elements (ancestors or siblings) that are required according to the problem you've defined in the question. And, of course, the JavaScript. Consider creating a [runnable 'snippet'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: @DavidThomas Snippet done! Sorry, it's the first I do all of this.

Comment: What about using `querySelectorAll()`?

Comment: Once the "Load Type" of your fiddle is fixed, I get the correct label output in the console. https://jsfiddle.net/wc8mzz3p/151/

Comment: If you use jQuery, better never do `onclick="function()`, use jquery $(selector). It makes it easier.

Comment: dont understand what u want ,hv any demo ?

Comment: Yes, the label output is correct but what I want is to copy the content I write in the field to the other field (by clicking the button), but when I do this it returns a null error in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR : Here is [a working Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a2pyrcsv/15/) for your problem.

Firstly, you should have your (HTML) code indented so that it's easier to read.

```
<div id='main'>
    <div id="rightSidePanel" class="ui form">
        <div id="compareForm" class="fields grid-no-margin">
            <div id="prjFormLeft" class="seven wide field">
                <div class='ui stackable one column grid grid-no-margin tab active'>
                    <div class='column field'>
                        <label for='Customer'>Customer</label>
                        <input id="left-input" type='text' field='Customer' name='Customer' />
                        <div class='ui item'>
                            <button id="left-button" class='ui right floated icon button' for='Customer' side='Left'>
                            <i class='right chevron icon'></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="prjFormRight" class="seven wide field">
                <div class='ui stackable one column grid grid-no-margin tab active'>
                    <div class='column field'>
                        <label for='Customer'>Customer</label>
                        <input id="right-input" type='text' name='Customer' />
                        <div class='ui item'>
                            <button id="right-button" class='ui icon button' for='Customer' side='Right'>
                                <i class='right chevron icon'></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that `<input />` is a self-closing HTML tag. Check out this [self-closing HTML tag list](http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html)

Let's now focus on the JavaScript part.

```
function transferInputVal(takeFrom, sendTo) {
  const fromEl = document.getElementById(`${takeFrom}-input`);
  const toEl = document.getElementById(`${sendTo}-input`);

  toEl.value = fromEl.value;
  fromEl.value = '';
}

const leftBtnEl = document.getElementById('left-button');
const rightBtnEl = document.getElementById('right-button');

leftBtnEl.addEventListener('click', () => transferInputVal('left', 'right'));
rightBtnEl.addEventListener('click', () => transferInputVal('right', 'left'));
```

The goal here is the following: when you click on a button, we get the inputs and assign to the one the value of the other. Then we clear the input the value is coming from, this is of course optional.

To do this, we've written a function `transferInputVal` that takes two parameters, `takeFrom` and `sendTo`. We want to trigger this function when we click on a button.

For instance, if we want to takeFrom left and sendTo right, the transferInputVal will assign to the right input the value of the left one.

After declaring this function, we read the buttons from the DOM and create two variables that will hold a reference to its corresponding button.

Then we add an event listener `click` to each button. When a button is clicked, it will call the function passed in second parameter, written as an `arrow function` here for better readability.

Note that I've used few concepts introduced in the most recent version of JavaScript (ES6). You could be interested in learning more about this topic before you go further. I've written a document about this, [check it out if you want to](https://github.com/mbeaudru/modern-js-cheatsheet) =).